# Abelian and residually finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> If $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group then $G$ is residually finite.

I don't know if the result holds or not. I tried to follow the definition but could not go far. Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is **Exercise 4.2.15** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. (Well, proving the statement, not whether it's true.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $G$ be a finitely generated abelian group. Then $G \simeq \mathbb{Z}^n \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_r}$ for some $n,n_1,\dots,n_r$. Now consider the epimorphism $$G \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_k^n \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_r}$$ with $k$ arbitrarily large.

Comment: I see, this epimorphism is in fact an isomorphism. How to proceed further?

Comment: It cannot be an isomorphism when $n>0$ because $G$ is infinite but the image is finite. You need to prove that for any $g \in G$ there exists a $k$ such that $g$ is not in the kernel of this epimorphism.

Comment: Since G is hopfian, it must be an isomorphism

Comment: and also how did you get G is infinite?

Comment: You should read again the definition of a hopfian group: the epimorphism must be from a group to itself, otherwise you could conclude that any hopfian group is trivial since there is always an epimorphism $G \twoheadrightarrow \{1\}$.

Comment: ${\mathbb Z}$ denotes the additive groups of integers, which is an infinite group. You cannot have an isomorphism between a finite group and an infinite group.

Comment: I never said G is finite and @Seirios, I am talking about this particular case, here map is from G to itself.

Comment: So what is your problem exactly? I gave a hint and Derek Holt gave precisely what you have to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof without classification.

Let $G$ be f.g. abelian and $g\in G$ nonzero. Let $N$ be a maximal subgroup not containing $g$. Let us prove that $G'=G/N$ is finite: hence $g$ survives in the finite quotient and we are done.

Let $g$ be the image of $g$ in $G'$. Hence $g$ is contained in every nonzero subgroup of $G'$. If some element of $G'$ has infinite order, then it generates a cyclic subgroup, in which we can find a deep enough subgroup, not containing $g$, contradiction. Hence every element in $G'$ has finite order. If $g_1,\dots,g_k$ are finitely many generators for $G'$, say $n_ig_i=0$ for some $n_i>0$, hence if $n$ is the lcm of the $n_i$ we have $nG'=0$. Hence $G'$ is a quotient of $(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})^k$ thus is finite.

Comment: How can we see that there exists at least one maximal subgroup not containing $g$?